# Tensorflow uses too much memory when initializing with constants

Tags: python, numpy, memory-management, tensorflow

I've noticed a weird thing recently, Tensorflow seems to use too much memory when initializing the variables with constants. Can someone help me understand the example below?

```
$ python -m memory_profiler test.py 
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
Filename: test.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
 4  144.531 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
 5                             def go():
 6  907.312 MiB  762.781 MiB    a = np.arange(100000000)
 7  910.980 MiB    3.668 MiB    s = tf.Session()
 8 1674.133 MiB  763.152 MiB    b = tf.Variable(a)
 9 3963.000 MiB 2288.867 MiB    s.run(tf.variables_initializer([b]))
10 3963.145 MiB    0.145 MiB    print(s.run(b)[:10])
```

Comment: I don't follow.  What `constants` are you talking about?  Which memory increment is wrong?

Comment: a is a constant numpy array of size 100000000, I'm creating a tensorflow variable b and set it equal to a, and call variables_initializer() to initialize b. a itself is 762 MB, so is b, what I don't understand is how TF ends up using 4GB memory.

Comment: `a` is a large array (there's nothing 'constant' about it).  `b` is a `tf` object that apparently makes a copy of `a's` data.  Line 9 adds 3 'copies' of that data as well - or at least makes 3 objects of similar size.  I don't know if it's the `initializer` step or the `run` one that does that; maybe both.

Comment: I see, the point is why does it do that and how can I reduce memory consumption?

Comment: Do you know what the `Session.run` is doing?  Can you explain it?  If `a` is smaller I expect the memory use will be less.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You have 900MB stored in numpy array.
- tf.Variable(a) is equivalent to tf.Variable(tf.constant(a)). To create this constant, Python client appends 900MB constant to Graph object in Python runtime
- Session.run triggers TF_ExtendGraph which transfers the graph to TensorFlow C runtime, another 900MB
- session allocates 900MB for `b` `tf.Variable` object in TensorFlow runtime

This makes 3600MB of memory allocations. To save memory you could do something like this instead

```
a_holder = tf.placeholder(np.float32)
b = tf.Variable(a_holder)
sess.run(b.initializer, feed_dict={a_holder: np.arange(100000000)})
```

TLDR; avoid creating large constants.

Comment: Thank you so much! In fact, I was just reading same workaround you provided in a slightly relevant GitHub issue, anyways, this answer provided more insight than that comment, plus I believe it's more accessible for people in the future searching for the same problem. Thanks!